# get value of data-id on click of div

Tags: jquery

I have the following div:

```
     <div id="icon2323" data-id="2343434"  style="color: #0076c0;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".detail" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></div>
```

Within my query code, I have the following:

```
         $('div[id^="icon"]').on('click', function (e) {
             alert('here'); 
             // var dataId = $(e).data("id"); did not work              
         });
```

I tried:

```
  var dataId = $(e).data("id"); and tried to display the value but showed undefined.
```

my question is how do I get the value of data-id in this case.

Comment: $(e).data("id") is wrong. The correct syntax, as J08691 answered is $(this).data("id")

Comment: `e` is the *event* object.  Could also use `$(e.currentTarget)` but `$(this)` is much simpler

Comment: Side not being using `e.target` or `e.currentTarget` would allow for the use of arrow functions as callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use jQuery's [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```js
$('div[id^="icon"]').on('click', function(e) {
  alert( $(this).data('id') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="icon2323" data-id="2343434" style="color: #0076c0;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".detail" class="fa fa-chevron-down">abc</div>
```

With plain JavaScript you use the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) property:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('div[id^="icon"]');
el.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert(this.dataset.id);
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="icon2323" data-id="2343434" style="color: #0076c0;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".detail" class="fa fa-chevron-down">abc</div>
```